# application is not listed in play store in Arabic but works in English

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I have published an application in Play store, and in Store Listing (in dev console) I have added Arabic translation to the existing English listing. Now when I search for the app in English it pops up as the first option which is perfect, but when I search in Arabic I can't find it at all. I tried and switched the default language to Arabic but nothing changed. I would really appreciate your help and suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the develop console check under **Pricing & Distribution** -> **Countries** if Arabic is checked.

It might also take a while for the app to be pushed to different servers from google. An app might show up much later on a different device if that device is connected to a different server from google. This may even result in a difference in the playstore listings within the same country.

For any other issues try this support page from google:

> https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en

Comment: I have checked and all countries have been selected. any other suggestions? thanks

Comment: How long has it been since you've published the update?

Comment: last update (when I switched the default to Arabic) 10 hours.

Comment: This support page should help you further https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en

Comment: Arabic is a language, how can we find in the country list?

Comment: Same issue i m facing. Any solution?